# Pytorch tensor shape

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, dimensions

I have a simple question regarding the shapes of 2 different tensors - `tensor_1` and `tensor_2`.

1. `tensor_1.shape` outputs `torch.Size([784, 1])`;
2. `tensor_2.shape` outputs `torch.Size([784])`.

I understand that the first one is rank-2 tensor, whereas the second is rank-1. What's hard for me is to conceptualize the difference between shape `[784, 1]` and `[784]`.

Is it correct to think that `tensor_1` has 784 rows and 1 column with a scalar inside each place? If so, why can't we call it simply a column vector (which is, in fact, rank-1 tensor), which also has values displayed vertically?

Similarly, can the shape of the second tensor (`[784]`) be imagined as 784 values inside a horizontal vector?

Comment: You’re a bit too hopeful about mapping Pytorch concepts onto mathematical concepts. There isn’t a distinction in Pytorch between row vectors and column vectors, for instance. There’s just rank-1 vectors.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, thank you! I needed this clarification. :)

Answer (score 3):

You cant call `tensor_1` as column vector because of its dimension . indexing that particular tensor is done in 2D
eg . `tensor_1[1,1]`

Coming to `tensor_2` , its a scalar tensor having only one dimension.
And of course you can make it have a shape of `tensor_1`, just do

```
tensor_2 = tensor_2.unsqueeze(1)   #This method will make tensor_2 have a shape of tensor_1
```

Comment: Thank you, Prajot. It makes sense. Maybe this is a dumb question, but what is there a specific reason behind having a `tensor_1` of shape `[784, 1]` instead of just `[784]` (same as `tensor_2`)? We can easily reshape `[784, 1]` into `[784]` by `tensor_1.view(784)` and reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: there are many reason for having shape of `[784, 1]` instaed of `[784]`. One reason would be batches.when you have single value inputs, & you want to send it through a batches,and your loss function expects your value in 2D shape rather than 1D shape.